# Show that the inclusion $X_0 \hookrightarrow ֓X$ induces an isomorphism $\pi_1(X_0, x_0) \to \pi_1(X, x_0)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

> If $X_0$ is the path-component of a space $X$ containing the basepoint $x_0$, show that the inclusion $X_0 \hookrightarrow ֓X$ induces an isomorphism $\pi_1(X_0, x_0) \to \pi_1(X, x_0)$.

Consider the homomorphism $\iota_* : \pi_1(X_0, x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$ defined by $\iota_*([f])=[\iota \circ f]$ where $\iota: X_0 \hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion map.

To show that $\iota_*$ is surjective we let $f:I \to X$ be a loop at $x_0$. Then since $x_0 \in X_0$ and $X_0$ is a path-component of $X$ the image $f(I)$ must be a subset of $X_0$ as otherwise $f$ couldn't be a loop.

Thus $\iota \circ f = f$ and we conclude that $\iota_*([f])=[\iota \circ f] = [f]$ making $\iota_*$ surjective.

To show that it's injective let $f,g :I \to X$ be loops at $x_0$. The images are again contained in $X_0$ by the same argument as before so if $\iota_*([f])=\iota_*([g]) \iff [\iota \circ f] = [\iota \circ g] \iff [f] = [g].$ So $\iota_*$ is an isomorphism.

I am wondering if I omit something here as I don't touch the homotopic properties of any loops in the argument?

Comment: The proof of injectivity could use more details (instead of "by the same argument"), otherwise, it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

> I am wondering if I omit something here as I don't touch the homotopic properties of any loops in the argument?

You claim that $[\iota \circ f] = [\iota \circ g] \iff [f] = [g]$ but you didn't actually show that.

> The images are again contained in $X_0$ by the same argument as before so (...)

Just because images of $f,g$ are contained in $X_0$ is not enough. For example if $X=D^2$ is the $2$-dimensional disk and $X_0=S^1$ is its boundary, then the "$\Rightarrow$" implication is not true ($D^2$ is contractible while $S^1$ has non-trivial fundemantal group). But of course $S^1$ is not a path-component of $D^2$.

Consider this equivalence:

$$[\iota \circ f] = [\iota \circ g] \iff [f] = [g]$$

The "$\Leftarrow$" implication is quite straight forward. You just take a homotopy $I\times I\to X_0$ and compose it with $\iota$. And it is enough if $\iota$ is continuous, regardless of what $X_0$ is and how $\iota$ is defined.

But the "$\Rightarrow$" implication requires more explanation. The core observation is that if $H:I\times I\to X$ is a homotopy from $\iota\circ f$ to $\iota\circ g$, then $x_0$ is in its image and therefore $im(H)\subseteq X_0$. Because the image is path-connected and $X_0$ is the path component of $x_0$. And so it induces $\widetilde{H}:I\times I\to X_0$, $\widetilde{H}(t,s)=H(t,s)$ homotopy from $f$ to $g$.